# PyCharm externals tools added to the menu bar disappear on restart

Tags: pycharm

I'm running PyCharm on Xubuntu.  We have several "external tools" setup in a shared XML file symlinked into our config directories.  I've tried adding the top-level external tools item to the menu and the toolbar and it works just fine until I restart PyCharm.  When I do the menu and button are missing.  If I go into the settings they are still there, they just don't show up.  Removing and re-adding them works until I restart again.

Any advise on resolving or troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what it is you're asking though...

Comment: I think this is a pycharm bug, You might want to report on JetBrain bug report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW?

Comment: Thanks for the link XPLOT1ON, I actually tried to find their bug tracking system but was unable to find it the other day.  Looks like this is an open bug going back to 2009.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5594